# Azure Kubernetes - Prometheus Automatic Service Discovery?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, prometheus, azure-aks

I have installed and configured Prometheus on my Azure Kubernetes as per the following configuration

```
prometheus_values.yaml
======================
global:
  scrape_interval: 1m
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  evaluation_interval: 1m
# Forcing Kubelet metrics scraping on http 
kubelet:
  enabled: true
  serviceMonitor:
    https: false
# Disabling scraping of Master Nodes Components
kubeControllerManager:
  enabled: false
kubeScheduler:
  enabled: false
kubeEtcd:
  enabled: false
kubeProxy:
  enabled: false
scrape_configs:
- job_name: dev-go-app
  static_configs:
  - targets: ['40.x.x.x:8080']
- job_name: default-go-app
  static_configs:
  - targets: ['40.x.x.x:8080']
```

and installed prometheus as shown below

```
Installing prometheus
=====================
helm upgrade --install prometheus \
--namespace monitoring \
stable/prometheus \
--values prometheus_values.yaml
```

It looks like I have to manually update the Prometheus configuration and apply for each application which is a difficult task especially when I have 100+ applications in the same Azure Kubernetes cluster.

Is there a way to let Prometheus automatically discovery the Kubernetes services and start pulling the metrics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using bare Prometheus, I suggest setting up a `kube-prometheus-stack` (formerly `prometheus-operator`): https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack

This stack has a built-in discovery mechanism in it - a CRD called `ServiceMonitor`: https://coreos.com/operators/prometheus/docs/latest/user-guides/running-exporters.html. This is a selector which will auto-discover your services thru labels, further discover pods behind these services, and load them into Prometheus scrape config.